# Limits and counters in the query conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a table, each row (among other things) have these fields:

- `order_overall_limit` overall impressions limit (can be 0 - without a limits, or a number);
- `order_daily_limit` daily impressions limit (can be 0 - without a limits, or a number);
- `order_hourly_limit` hourly impressions limit (can be 0 - without a limits, or a number);
- `order_overall_counter` total impressions counter (never zeroed);
- `order_daily_counter` daily impressions counter (zeroed once a day);
- `order_hourly_counter` hourly impressions counter (zeroed once a hour).

I'm trying to write a query that will follow these rules:

- If `order_overall_limit`=0 or `order_overall_limit`<`order_overall_counter` - then show this record
- If `order_daily_limit`=0 or `order_daily_limit`<`order_daily_counter` - then show this record
- If `order_hourly_limit`=0 or `order_hourly_limit`<`order_hourly_counter` - then show this record
- If the overall limit is over (`order_daily_limit`>=`order_daily_counter`) - then do not show this record, regardless of other limits.
- If the overall limit is ok, but the daily limit is over (`order_daily_limit`>=`order_daily_counter`) - then do not show this record, regardless of hourly limit.
- If the overall and daily limits are ok, but the hourly limit is over (`order_hourly_limit`>=`order_hourly_counter`) - then do not show this record.
- If `order_overall_limit`=0 - then we don't have the overall limit.
- If `order_daily_limit`=0 - then we don't have the daily limit.
- If `order_hourly_limit`=0 - then we don't have the hourly limit.

I tried to do it like this, but it works wrong (for example, this query ignore the daily limit, if the overall limit is set, but not over yet):

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` 
WHERE
    (`order_overall_limit`=0 OR `order_overall_counter`<`order_overall_limit` )
AND (`order_daily_limit`=0 OR `order_daily_counter`<`order_daily_limit` ) 
AND (`order_hourly_limit`=0 OR `order_hourly_counter`<`order_hourly_limit`)
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `AND` means that *both* conditions have to be true. You want `OR`.

Comment: It's really confusing to describe this in both positive and negative terms. It's hard to tell what takes priority. Either say what should be shown or say what shouldn't be shown.

Comment: Because of the dependencies, this will probably need to be nested `IF` functions or `CASE` expressions.

Comment: `IF(some condition, true, IF(some other condition, true, IF(...)))`